# Field values are not changing

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, screen-flow

I'm trying to use an aura component if I can able to change those values on the second screen every time I pressed Previous button in a screen flow.

I have a list of related child records on the first screen and when I click **NEXT** button, it will show various fields with values where a user can modify each field.

But the problem is, the values from the *first child record* that I selected are still showing after clicking the **Previous** button and select a different child record.

I find this code in [developer salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_screens_replace_footer.htm) and still, I can't change the values on my second screen flow. After having this aura component to my flow, I set the **Advanced** to Refresh inputs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Store the child record value in a variable and manually reset the value on footer action